# is ajax post with basic http authentication possible using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code which tries to post to a api. But I keep getting 401 in firefox and 400 in safari

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://url.com",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "false",
        data: form_data,
        beforeSend: function(xhr1) {
          xhr1.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password))
        },
        success: function (data,status,xhr){
          //do something
        }
      });
```

I followed instructions from here 
http://dothow.blogspot.com/2009/05/http-basic-authentication-with-jquery.html?showComment=1270999665472#c3021624182011440325

*encodeBase64 is part of a library function

Comment: Observe the request headers using Firebug or similar. Then make the request directly in a web page without using XMLHTTPRequest. Compare the headers to spot the differencee.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to use `username` and `password` properties of `$.ajax`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I tried username and password as well. In firefox I get a big error `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Success arg 1 [nsIDOMDocumentXBL.getBindingParent]"  nsresult: "0x0 (NS_OK)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/tree.xml :: onxblunderflow :: line 947"  data: no]` and safari the same 400 bad request